# How to get persistent iAds over different view controllers in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, view, iad, viewcontroller

I have been looking around and can't find information on how to do this.

I have a game and the ad loads as a banner on launch at the bottom, when I select a game mode it changes to that view controller and an ad is relaunched at the bottom of the screen.

How can I get the same ad to continue appearing at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Adding your viewController as child.

Comment: How do I do that? Is there a reference you can guide me to?

Answer (score 0):

For Adding your viewcontroller as a ChildViewController try the following :

1) In your main view add the UIView which is container containing your other view controllers and having frame of your full view controller except your iAD view. create outlet for your container.

2)on your button click(or when you want to add another ViewController):

```
storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
childViewController * mens = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childViewController"];
mens.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, self.Container.frame.size.width, self.Container.frame.size.height);

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[self.Container.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self addChildViewController:mens];
[self.Container addSubview:mens.view];
[mens didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

here "childViewController" is my another ViewController which i want to add.